# Causality and wave configurations in dispersive media

Tags: special-relativity, waves, interference, causality

As motivation, consider if I handed you two photographs of a ball at two different times, and asked you if it were possible for the ball to have traveled as far as it did in a certain time. In the example below, the photographs are at two times.

[image]

Clearly, the ball could have traveled fine between those points. But if I had handed you the following two photographs,

[image]

you would certainly let me know that there is no way for the ball to have traveled so far in such a short time. (The background spacetime is Minkowski.)

The story seems to me to be different for waves. In particular, interference makes interpreting snapshots difficult.
For example, in the below I have snapshots of $t=0$ and $t=1$ second. My x-axis is in light-seconds. It looks like the bump has moved a distance of $3$ light-seconds. Nevertheless, this is OK.

[image]
[image]

To see why this is ok, consider the following animation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7p7v.jpg . The function, plotted with Mathematica, is $\frac {2} {11}\sqrt {10\pi} e^{-10 (t - x + 2)^2}\left (e^{40 (t - x + 1)} - e^{-40 t (x - 2)} + 1 \right)$. (This can be put into a canonical $f(x-t)+g(x+t)$ form.)

What is happening is that I have two wavepackets propagating to the right, and one wavepacket with negative amplitude propagating to the left. At $t=0$, the right-propagating wavepackets are at $x=0$ and $x=2$, and the left-propagating wavepacket is at $x=2$, destructively interfering with the rightmost right-propagating wavepacket. At $t=1$, the right-propagating wavepackets are at $x=1$ and $x=3$, and the left-propagating wavepacket is at $x=1$, destructively interfering with the leftmost right-propagating wavepacket.

So it is not that the wavepacket in the snapshot traveled a too-large distance; it is that the snapshots are showing two different wavepackets, with the other wavepacket in each snapshot destructively interfering with another. Thus causality is perfectly intact.

---

It is clear that one must be careful in interpreting snapshots when we have interference. Furthermore, the wave example was perhaps somewhat fine-tuned - I can only engineer this sort of cancellation if my final wavepacket position at $t=1$ is an odd integer number of light seconds away from the initial position ($x=2n+1$ corresponds to $n+1$ right-moving packets and n left-moving packets). My question is:  if the medium was instead dispersive, can I still construct such a perfect cancellation to give snapshots yielding a peak at $x=0$ at $t=0$ and a peak much further away at $t=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, because in dispersive medium such simple peak patterns can't move so quietly leaving zero oscillations behind. They will instead broaden and they can manifest oscillations in space with many different spatial frequencies.